# How do I count the number of values in a particular key in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So if I have a Dictionary that takes multiple values (i.e `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`) And I have a key called A that contains values B and C and D. So I need to count the elements of the list for the particular key A. Therefore the counter should equal 3.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the declaration of Dictionary in your case

Comment: I edited it. Sorry I forgot about the spaces thing!

Comment: Use dict["key"].Count , but make sure you first check that key exist to avoid exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're positive the key exists, just access it and count the items in the value.

```
var count = yourDictionary["A"].Count;
```

If you're not sure, then use `TryGetValue`:

```
List<string> values = "";
if (yourDictionary.TryGetValue("A", out values))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of elements in {0}: {1}", "A", values.Count);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key {0} not found!", "A");
}
```

Comment: Starting with C# 7.0, you can declare the out variable in the argument list of the method call, rather than in a separate variable declaration: `if (yourDictionary.TryGetValue("A", out var values))`

Answer (score 2):

If Your Dictionary is like as `Dictionary<string,List<T>> myDic;`

Then the accessing can do such as follows,

```
int count = myDic["A"].Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should solve your problem.

```
int temp = YourDict["A"].ToString().Count();
```

Comment: Haven't you notice your answer is the same as accepted answer but with less detail?

Comment: @HardcoreGamer actually i wasn't able to produce results with that one so i just posted which worked for me.

Comment: Wait, I misunderstand your answer. You answer is not correct, are you sure your dictionary is `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: It's 'Dictionary<string, int>'.

Comment: OK. But the question is about `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` though.